# In JetBrains Rider, how to hide directory output in Console?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-rider

How to hide directory output in Console in JetBrains Rider?

[image]

Comment: This is not "Directory output". it's a command that the IDE executes. It is for you to see what params get passed/what paths are used. This allows you to see what may be wrong with paths, see the possible difference when running the command in the IDE and outside etc etc. AFAIK there is no option to not to show such an info there.